# Let a, b, m be integers. Prove that if 3a + 7b ≥ 10, then a > 7m-7 or b > -3m+3

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I really need assistance on this as I do not know where to begin from.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Assume $a\le -7m-7$ and $b\le -3m+3$ and aim for a contradiction.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a\le 7m-7\land b\le-3m+3$.  Then $3a+7b\le3(7m-7)+7(-3m+3)=0\lt10$.  Contradiction.

Comment: Clear and concise, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Setting $c \doteq 7m-7$ and $d \doteq  -3m+3$, note that $3c + 7d = 0$ (not matter what integer $m$ is).

So if the relation $3a + 7d \geq 10 > 0 = 3c+7d $ holds, then the strict inequality $3a+7b> 3c+7d$ holds, which implies either $3a > 3c$ (which would imply $a>c = 7m-7$) or $7d > 7b$, (which would imply $d>b = -3m+3$).